# How to fill in missing points on a graph?

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

If I plot the function

```
Plot[Surd[x, 10], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}}]
```

I get
[image]

This issue I have is that graph does not extend down to the origin.  If you look at the function Surd[x, 10] in any textbook it will go down to the origin.  I realize why its doing what it is doing in Mathematica.    Never the less, I would still like the graph to extend down to the origin so that it visually correct.  Anyone know of a nifty way to handle this type of situation?

I have tried changing PlotPoints and MaxRecursion but neither seem to make a big enough difference in this situation.

Comment: A work around is `Plot[Surd[x, 10], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], Red}] /. 
 Line[x__] :> Line[Join[{{0, 0}}, x]]`

Comment: If you add `PlotTheme -> "Classic"` then you will not notice this.

Comment: That's amusing. I tried `Plot[x^(1/n), {x, 0, 0.1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}] ` with various natural ns. Starting from `n=5 ` the effect is present, and it increases with `n `. A bug?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch No, one would have to very fine points sampling near `0` to get details. This is a duplicate question, before I find it here's how you go work around that: `ParametricPlot[{x, Surd[x, 10]}, {x, 0, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Thickness@.02]`